# Disable taxonomy pages

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Are there any way to disable the taxonomy pages? I saw a question that restricts access to them ([Original question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30103/blocking-access-to-taxonomy-pages)).

But I dont want the "access denied" message to be displayed, I want to remove the pages completely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need taxonomy you can always just disable the module.

If you still need the functionality but don't want the display pages to exist I guess you could implement `hook_menu_alter()` to remove them from the registry:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  unset($items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']);
  unset($items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/view']);
  unset($items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/feed']); // If you want to hide the feed as well.
}
```

I'd do some thorough testing after doing that though, I'm not sure if it would have any knock-on effects. Also if you're using the default taxonomy View for your taxonomy pages you'll obviously need to disable that as well.

Comment: Thanks, will keep an eye on things to see if something strange happens

Comment: Oh that's clever. Probably cleaner than trying to do a permissions-based denial.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but definitely worth adding another answer to due to Google pointing a lot of questions here.

I believe a great option for this issue would be [Disable Term Node Listings](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_term_node_listings) module which allows you to 404 or 403 the taxonomy listing pages based on vocabulary.

**EDIT**

Updating my own answer here, the module above does not disable the /feed paths so is useless for those. I'll be utilising a hook_menu_alter to kill those.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread looking for the same functionality, and wanted to post another option I've found:

[the Rabbit Hole module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole)

(35k reported installs as of 2020-03), which allows to disable the default pages for nodes, terms, and other entities, with a variety of options, including per bundle and per entity.

Answer (score 0):

So this is slightly more complicated than @Clive's response, but it's a bit more specific and probably more isolated. Basically, the strategy is to use `hook_init()` to redirect to a 404 page.

```
function mymodule_init() {
  $path_requested = explode("/", request_uri());
  if (isset($path_requested[1]) && $path_requested[1] == 'whatever_the_first_part_is') {
    drupal_goto('page-not-found');
  }
}
```

This is assuming you have a generic page not found page. There is a common approach for this that goes like this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['page-not-found'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'error_handling_page_not_found',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function error_handling_page_not_found() {
  drupal_set_title('404\'d dood!');
  $cust_err = 'Still reticulating splines....';
  return $cust_err;
}
```